# Is there a correct way to parse output in Bash from a command?

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-redshift, psql

I'm using `psql` to run a few commands, where the last one is something similar to: `select max(id) from tablename`. I'm trying to get the id of the last row inserted. It returns the correct value `(7)` in this scenario.

```
Begin Informatica Script SET INSERT 0 1 max ----- 7 (1 row) Redshift Delta copy completed at: 04/10/17 17:45:21 END
```

However, I'm trying to parse it and have no idea what to do... Is there a way to limit the output to just the value of `7`? If not, how do I grab just the number? There is the possibility of this becoming a rather large number as well, like `10,000`

Edit: I added 2 options `-qt` and got the output down to:

```
Begin Informatica Script 9 Redshift Delta copy completed at: 04/10/17 17:53:53 END
```

In that, `9` is the ID I want.

Comment: Are there always `-----`, one whitespace, one or more digits, one whitespace followed by `(`?

Comment: Not anymore. I added 2 options to the `psql` command and got the output stripped down a little

Comment: Is there always `Begin Informatica Script`, one whitespace, one or more digits, one whitespace followed by `Redshift Delta`?

Comment: Yep, `Begin Informatica Script` is from an `echo` statement at the beginning of the script and `Redshift Delta` is from another echo statement at the end of the script, which contains the SQL

Comment: A much better solution if you can modify the generating script is to have it output machine-readable output, either by omitting the parts you don't want, or by wrapping it in something like JSON. The diagnostic messages you include look like they have no business in the program's standard output anyway (progress messages etc should be sent to standard error).

Comment: There are **much** better ways to read content from PostgreSQL into a shell script. You can specify your own chosen delimiter both between records and between fields. If you make these be nonprintable characters that can't exist in your data, then you can read fields positionally in a way that is not at all dependent on whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
echo 'Begin Informatica Script 9 Redshift Delta copy completed at: 04/10/17 17:53:53 END' | sed -r 's/.*Begin Informatica Script ([0-9,]+) Redshift Delta.*/\1/'
```

Output:

```
9
```

Comment: Do I need to add in single quotes at all with the way I'm trying to do it: `logStart=$( sh execute.sh ExecutionLogStart.sql heelo | sed -r 's/.*Begin Informatica Script (.*) Redshift Delta.*/\1/' ); echo $logStart`

Comment: Single or double quotes are required for `s///` or try `sed -r s/.\*Begin\ Informatica\ Script\ \(.\*\)\ Redshift\ Delta.\*/\\1/`.

Comment: Cool, that works if I do `echo $logStart` so I'll go  ahead and accept it. Doesn't seem to work with the command substitution... Do you know how to properly send the output of the `sh` command to be split by `sed`? The echo at the end is outputting the entire line still

Comment: Try to replace `heelo` by `heelo 2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout.